Send swap transaction in python
I'm currently working on the Eclipse testnet (similar to Solana in terms of code, but with a different RPC). You can view the transaction I'm referencing here: (https://explorer.dev.eclipsenetwork.xyz/tx/4zqJfiVHGHKfAA18qdiYGAk46Cp6BtMmGz4qiY8sRKvNe4rPQmmZocHnra57XywPUujAy9M4xQQH3JG13tNGS9Kc?cluster=testnet).
I've encountered issues with parameter transmission, and I am struggling to understand how to interact with the DEX (https://eclipse.invariant.app/swap). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any documentation. Any guidance or feedback would be greatly appreciated.
As an example, I tried to take this transaction and replicate it exactly. I get a response that the transaction is sent, but it never appears on the blockchain.
Here's the code I'm using
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.keypair import Keypair
from solana.transaction import AccountMeta, Instruction, Signature, Transaction
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from main import key
import base58

# Initialize the client
client = Client("https://testnet.dev2.eclipsenetwork.xyz")
sender = Keypair.from_base58_string(key)

# Signature of the transaction you see in the explorer
transaction_signature = Signature.from_string("4zqJfiVHGHKfAA18qdiYGAk46Cp6BtMmGz4qiY8sRKvNe4rPQmmZocHnra57XywPUujAy9M4xQQH3JG13tNGS9Kc")

# Get transaction details
transaction_details = client.get_transaction(transaction_signature, commitment=Confirmed)

transaction_info = transaction_details.value.transaction.transaction
message = transaction_info.message
instructions = message.instructions

# Get the list of signers
num_signers = len(transaction_info.signatures)
signers_pubkeys = [message.account_keys[i] for i in range(num_signers)]

# Create a transaction
transaction = Transaction()

# Add instructions from the original transaction
for instruction in instructions:
    program_id_index = instruction.program_id_index
    program_id = message.account_keys[program_id_index]

    accounts = [
        AccountMeta(
            pubkey=message.account_keys[account],
            is_signer=(message.account_keys[account] == sender.pubkey()),
            is_writable=True
        )
        for account in instruction.accounts
    ]

    if accounts == []:
        accounts = [
            AccountMeta(
                pubkey=sender.pubkey(),
                is_signer=True,
                is_writable=True
            )
        ]

    data = base58.b58decode(instruction.data)

    transaction.add(
        Instruction(
            accounts=accounts,
            program_id=program_id,
            data=data
        )
    )

# Sign and send the transaction
response = client.send_transaction(transaction, sender, opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=True, preflight_commitment=Confirmed))
print(response)

Despite following this process, my transaction doesn't appear on the blockchain. Can someone help me identify what I might be doing wrong or point me towards any available documentation for interacting with the DEX on the Eclipse testnet?
Thank you in advance for any assistance!
